# How i can avoid writing this 120 times?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

im currently coding a rainfall model in python and am at the stage where i need to average the monthly rainfalls over the 10 years, seperated by year.

how can i avoid writing this code 120 times?

i really cannot find a way to do it, ive tried writing a function but the one i wrote required me to have a list for every month of every year - so would still need 120 times.

below is the code i wrote for 1, 1 - being january of the first year:

```
seasonal_rainfall = []
january_rainfall_amount =[]


for i in range(len(rainfall)):
    if rainfall.loc[i, "Year Tag"] ==1 and rainfall.loc[i, "Month Tag"] ==1:
        daily_amount = rainfall.loc[i, "Amount (mm)"]
        january_rainfall_amount.append(daily_amount)
    else:
        pass
month_amount = sum(january_rainfall_amount)
```

the full code needed for this to run is below - some of it could probably be made a lot better but i am very new to python:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import openpyxl
import tempfile
import xlsxwriter

#pww = float(input("PWW value:\n"))
pww = 0.7
#pdd = float(input("PDD Value: \n"))
pdd = 0.6
pwd = float(1 - pww)
pdw = float(1 - pdd)
#onelam = float(input("1 / lambda value:\n"))
onelam = 3.1
lda = 1/onelam



rainfall = pd.DataFrame({
    "Day": range(1, 3651),
    "Random 1": np.random.rand(3650),
    "Random 2": np.random.rand(3650)
})

state = [1]

for i in range(1, len(rainfall)):
    prev_state = state[-1]
    random_value = rainfall.loc[i, "Random 2"]

    if prev_state > 0:
        new_state = 1 if random_value < pww else 0
    else:
        new_state = 1 if random_value < pdw else 0

    state.append(new_state)


rainfall["State"] = state

amounts = []

for i in range(0, len(rainfall)):
    random = rainfall.loc[i, "Random 1"]
    one_random = 1 - random

    if state[i] > 0:
        amount = (-abs(1) * math.log(one_random))/lda
    else: amount = 0

    amounts.append(amount)

rainfall["Amount (mm)"] = amounts


total_rainfall = rainfall["Amount (mm)"].sum()

january = []
february =[]
march =[]
april =[]
may =[]
june =[]
july =[]
august =[]
september =[]
october =[]
november =[]
december =[]

for i in range(1,29):
    february.append(2)

for i in range(1,32):
    january.append(1)
    march.append(3)
    may.append(5)
    july.append(7)
    august.append(8)
    october.append(10)
    december.append(12)
    
for i in range(1,31):
    april.append(4)
    june.append(6)
    september.append(9)
    november.append(11)

year = january + february + march + april + may + june + july + august + september + october + november + december
ten_years_monthly = 10 * year
rainfall["Month Tag"] = ten_years_monthly

year1 =[]
year2=[]
year3=[]
year4=[]
year5=[]
year6=[]
year7=[]
year8=[]
year9=[]
year10=[]

for i in range(0,364):
    year1.append(1)
for i in range(364,730):
    year2.append(2)
for i in range(730, 1095):
    year3.append(3)
for i in range(1095, 1460):
    year4.append(4)
for i in range(1460, 1825):
    year5.append(5)
for i in range(1825,2190):
    year6.append(6)
for i in range(2190,2555):
    year7.append(7)
for i in range(2555, 2920):
    year8.append(8)
for i in range(2920, 3285):
    year9.append(9)
for i in range(3285, 3650):
    year10.append(10)

ten_years_yearly = year1 + year2 +year3+year4+year5+year6+year7+year8+year9+year10
rainfall["Year Tag"] = ten_years_yearly

seasonal_rainfall = []
january_rainfall_amount =[]


for i in range(len(rainfall)):
    if rainfall.loc[i, "Year Tag"] ==1 and rainfall.loc[i, "Month Tag"] ==1:
        daily_amount = rainfall.loc[i, "Amount (mm)"]
        january_rainfall_amount.append(daily_amount)
    else:
        pass
month_amount = sum(january_rainfall_amount)
print(month_amount)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to write the same code 120 times? You already are using loops, can you not use one to repeat the same code 120 times?

Comment: "but the one i wrote required me to have a list for every month of every year - so would still need 120 times" - do you know you can have a list *of* lists?

Comment: @mkrieger1 12 months x 10 years, surely i will need to calculate 120 different variables?

Comment: `i need to average the monthly rainfalls over the 10 years, seperated by year.` Couldn't you do this with groupby? e.g. `df.groupby(['Year', 'Month'])['Amount (mm)'].sum()`. You'd also need to convert from day-of-year to year and month, but Pandas has built in tools for that.

Comment: @NickODell is that possible for theoretical days? the model produces rainfall for an undated 10 year period

Comment: You can interpret your 'Days' variable as the number of days since some specific date. Example: `pd.to_timedelta(df['Days'],'d') + datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)`. This will handle the lengths of the different months, but it won't handle leap years correctly. (Which isn't possible without knowing what year it is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i worked it out with the help of @NickODell 's comments:

```
groupedby_month = (rainfall.groupby(["Year Tag", "Month Tag"], as_index=False)["Amount (mm)"])
groupedby_month_df_sum = pd.DataFrame(groupedby_month.sum())

groupedby_year = groupedby_month_df_sum.groupby(["Year Tag"], as_index=False)["Amount (mm)"]
groupedby_year_df_sum = pd.DataFrame(groupedby_year.sum())
```

gives the output i need:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid creating 120 different variables (one for each month of a 10-year span), by using a single list to store all the values for each month. For example:

```
amounts = []
for i in range(120):
    amounts.append(0)
```

This would create a list of 120 zeros. You can access the value for a particular month/year by calculating the index for that month/year combination. Just keep in mind that list indexing starts at 0:

```
year = 2  # Year 3
month = 8 # Month 9
value = amounts[year * 12 + month]
```

Hope that puts you on the right path.